# What is that passage in the Bible where Peter hopes that all will be saved?

Tags: bible, new-testament, reference-request

As a child I was an avid Bible reader, now I don't do it anymore, and there are some time  phrases still lingering in my mind from that period.

Anybody knows what is the passage when Peter hopes and says that everybody will be saved by the mercy of God? I hope I am not erring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[2 Peter 3:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%203:9&version=NASB) ... maybe?

> The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some count slowness, but is patient toward you, not wishing for any to perish but for all to come to repentance.

Comment: @warren You are most probably right but then I think if God wishes something it has some pretty powerful tools on the hand including hell but also persuasion and love.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu - but humans also have free will to reject God :)